EventRecord cant get error message, only description
Hi i basically have the following code and it works perfectly, except that i cant get the error message thats shown in "General" when you open the Event Viewer app.
Another post said that er.FormatDescription() was the correct one tho it seems to be just a description as it never changes for the entry but the actual error messages do. Also it doesnt seem like the error message i want and is just a generic description.
So to be short:
How do i get the actual error?
void getEventLogs(string sourceName)
{
    clearListBox(listBox1);

    string queryString = string.Format("*[System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime>='{0}' and @SystemTime<='{1}']]]",
    DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-10).ToString("s"),
    DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("s"));
    var q = new EventLogQuery($"Microsoft-Windows-{sourceName}/Admin", PathType.LogName, queryString);
    var r = new EventLogReader(q);

    var list = new List<EventRecord>();

    EventRecord er = r.ReadEvent();
    while (er != null)
    {
        addListItem(er.FormatDescription(), listBox1);
    }
}

getEventLogs("TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager")

Many different stack overflow answers but it didnt work and couldnt make comments because i dont have enough internet points
